# Download chrome extension from site, without redirecting to Chrome Webstore page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a site and a chrome extension. And I want to promote this extension on site. When the user sees this promotion he can click on the button "Download extension", and currently it redirects the user to Chrome Webstore.

So, I want to implement the next flow:

1. User clicks on "Download extension" button
2. Installation of extension starts but without redirection to Webstore.

This must be an actual Chrome Webstore item, not a file saved on site.

It`s ok to show them alerts from Webstore or smth.  But I really want to do this without redirection.

Thank you)

Comment: You can't. Google [intentionally disabled it](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/06/improving-extension-transparency-for.html).

Comment: Tnx. Got it. Couldn't find it myself(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can`t do this without redirecting to the chrome web store.
Of course, you can give CRX file directly to the user and let them install the extension by their hands, but this, obviously, not the best choice in terms of user experience

Resolved with the next solution:

Right after the installation of extension - I create a tab with a page that I needed

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://mail.google.com',
    active: true
  });

  return false;
});
```

It is also possible to look at what tabs are open right now and bring a focus to the tab that we need:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  if ((details.reason === 'install') || (details.reason === 'update')) 
  { 
    refreshBrowser('gmail-inbox', true); 
  } 
}); 

function refreshBrowser(target, bringToForeground) {
  if (target !== 'gmail-inbox') return; 
  chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function(windows) 
  { 
    var foundExisting = false; 
    windows.forEach(function(win) 
    {
      win.tabs.forEach(function(tab) 
      { 
        // Ignore tabs not matching the target. 
        if (target === 'gmail-inbox') { 
          if (!/https:\/\/(mail|inbox)\.google\.com/.test(tab.url)) return; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
          return; // Unknown target. 
        } 
        // Reload the matching tab.  
        chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id); // If this is the first one found, activate it. 
        if (bringToForeground && !foundExisting) 
        {
          chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true }); } 
          foundExisting = true; 
        }); 
      }); 
      // If no gmail tab found, just open a new one. 
      if (bringToForeground && !foundExisting) 
      { 
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: (target === 'gmail-inbox') ? 'https://mail.google.com' : 'https://www.mixmax.com', active: true 
      });
    } 
  });
}
```

[Source](https://www.gmass.co/blog/redirect-user-to-website-after-installing-chrome-extension/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure. Tnx. Edited